# JasperReports alignment

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to generate something like this using *iReport*:

**From Address**

name :  $F{}

address : $F{}

city :  $F     , State : $F     , Zip : $F

Phone : $F

There is no restriction on length on any field, if any field overflows the below ones should also strech accordingly such that its properly aligned.

There is also **TO Address** just immediate right side of **From Address** . If any field overflows from either section, both sections should align themselves accordingly.

Its like, a page is divided into two parts and left side has from address and the right has to address at same y axis

Answer (score 0):

Put the following statement into **one** textfield: "city :"+$F+" , State : "+$F+" , Zip : "+$F

You can keep the others as they are. Then just stretch all text-fields to the middle of the page.